# Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present [Postman and Springboot]

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm passing a csv file as a parameter, but it is not being received at the backend code. I've looked into multiple available solutions, but none of them seemed to work for me. Here's the code:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/import",  consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public Object uploadCSVFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile csvFile, Model model) {
    String response = "";
    Object obj = null;
    if (csvFile.isEmpty()) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Please select a CSV file to upload.");
        model.addAttribute("status", false);
    } else {
        try{
               //doo foo
            }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Here are the dependencies in pom.xml if it's required for reference:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>r2dbc-h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Apache Commons FileUpload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Apache Commons IO -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.39</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
        <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Even on using "required=false" in the @RequestParam annotation, turns out the Multipart file is null, even though the inspect tool displays having sent it as a request. Any help is appreciated!

PS: Postman Snip: [image]

Headers snip:
[image]

Comment: Can you add your request please ? we need your postman screenshot

Comment: @BERGUIGAMohamedAmine I've updated the question by including the snip :]

Comment: can you show us the headers tab please? (and test your api without this prop consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE )

Comment: Did you set the `Content-Type` header to `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: @akuma8 yup, i did that, i've updated the question with new snip.

Comment: you import MultipartFile class from org.springframework.web.multiplart ?

Comment: @BERGUIGAMohamedAmine yep org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile it is

Comment: Ok, I see that you are using spring-webflux. So try this `uploadCSVFile(@RequestPart("file") FilePart file)`, `FilePart` is from `org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.FilePart`

Comment: can you please change the prop name from file to myFile and change @RequestParam("file") to @RequestParam("myFile") and check well on PostMan that you choose from-data as type and send image file in place of pdf file

Comment: @BERGUIGAMohamedAmine tried that one buddy, but thanks you made me realize that  the libs/dependencies could be an issue, i fixed it : ]

Answer (score 3):

Turns out, the comment from @BERGUIGAMohamedAmine made me realize that MultiPart is either not compatible / or has some issues with Spring webflux. In my case, I changed MultiPart to FilePart, and things are now working fine.
Here's the updated body:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/import",  consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public Object uploadCSVFile(@RequestPart("file") FilePart file, Model model) {
        //do foo
}
```

PS: @RequestParam can be used instead of @RequestPart, but it made sense to use it since we are trying to send a Part as a parameter, so I used it :]

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer, try using `@RequestPart("file")` instead of `@RequestParam("file")`.
See documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestPart.html

Comment: you can also use @RequestParam

Comment: Note that @RequestParam annotation can also be used to associate the part of a "multipart/form-data" request with a method argument supporting the same method argument types